# Java - Searching a folder and loading the .class files

Tags: java, classloader

How would I go about scanning a folder for name.class files and then loading them into the program into an arraylist.

I have a general idea of what I need it to do, I just don't know what I need to use to implement it in code.

Scan folder
Load .class files found
add the class into an arraylist using array.add( new class(params));
After all that running the methods that are in the class.

This is the current way I do my system of loading the modules (if they are even called that) into the client

```
 package pro.skid.Gabooltheking.Module;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ModuleLoader {

    public static ArrayList<Module> module = new ArrayList<Module>();
    public final ArrayList<Module> getModule(){ return module; }

    public static void startModule(){
        module.clear();
    }

        public final Module getModuleByName(String moduleName){  
            for( Module module : getModule()){
                if(module.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(moduleName)){ return module; }
            }
            return null;
        }

        public static void keyBind(int key){ 
            for(Module m : module){
                if(m.getKey() == key){
                    m.toggle();
                }
            }
        }

        public static void runModuleTick(){
            for(Module m : module){
                if(m.getState()){
                    m.onTick();
                }
            }
        }

}
```

This is how the abstract Module class looks like

```
package pro.skid.Gabooltheking.Module;

public abstract class Module {

    int key,color;
    String name;
    boolean state;

    /**
     * Set's the following variables
     * @param name- name of mod
     * @param key- keybind for mod
     * @param color- color in gui
     */
    public Module(String name, int key, int color){
        this.name = name;
        this.key = key;
        this.color = color;
    }
    /**
     * Set's the state of the mod to on or off.
     */
    public void toggle() 
    { state = !state; 
        if(this.getState())
            { 
             this.onToggle();
            }else{ 
             this.onDisable();
        } 
    }
    /**
     * Does something when mod is first toggled.
     * Does it only once.
     */
    public abstract void onToggle();

    /**
     * Does something when mod is disabled.
     * Does it only once.
     */
    public abstract void onDisable();

    /**
     * Does something when mod is toggled.
     * Loops untill hack is disabled.
     */
    public abstract void onTick();


    public String getName(){return this.name; }
    public int getKey(){ return this.key; }
    public int getColor(){ return this.color; }
    public boolean getState(){ return this.state; }
}
```

All help is good help in my opinion. Also ignore the crappy commenting that's more for me to remember what each method does.

Comment: Seems you are re-inventing a classloader?  why do you need to do that?

Comment: That isn't my initial goal. The current way I load mod's to manually add them to the .jar and manually add them to the arraylist through module.add(new class(params)); I would like it to be that I just drop the .class file into the folder and it loads them automatically without me ever having to add any of that myself.

Comment: If the folder is in the classpath, then a simple Class.forName will load the class for you.

Comment: The class will not be added until after I compile the client, and to that I don't even know what the name will be. That's why I need the folder to be scanned, but before scanned created.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache commons IOUtils and one of it's Filters to go through a directory recursively and match files based on name or extension.

If you do not want external dependencies, then the standard library java.io.File also contains several list methods that you may use.